# force https AND www on all pages except 1

Tags: .htaccess

We have software on our site that enables us to send SMS to our members. The software communicates with a third part api and they communicate delivery reports back to the site. This delivery report specifically needs http://www. The url the send the report to is

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=S6fd65thisisafakepasswordstring
```

Currently, I have all pages redirecting to https://www using this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force https:// for all except some selected URLs    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index.php?option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=S6fd65thisisafakepasswordstring/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php?option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=S6fd65thisisafakepasswordstring/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As you can see, I am trying to exclude the page in question from the force https://www protocol. It's not working. All my searches deal with either https or www, but not both. Any help here is appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Your RewriteCond is failing because you did not escape the `?` character  in your `THE_REQUEST` pattern. `?` is a special character in regex and it must be escaped if you want to match a literal `?` .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not going to address the really bad idea that is sending a password in a query string over an insecure connection. That's something you should take up with the third party running that API.

Now for why your RewriteRules might not be working.

According to the Apache variables [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#vars), `%{THE_REQUEST}` covers the full request line, not just the request URI or query string:

> **`THE_REQUEST`** | The complete request line (e.g., `"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"`)

You probably want to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` to capture those reports. So your rules would look something like:

```
# force https:// for all except some selected URLs  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or if you want to use `${THE_REQUEST}`, they would look like this:

```
# force https:// for all except some selected URLs  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^POST /index\.php\?option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=.+ HTTP/1\.1$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^POST /index\.php\?option=com_acysms&ctrl=deliveryreport&gateway=telerivet&pass=.+ HTTP/1\.1$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The request is in quotes because of the spaces, but you could just escape them with a `\` instead. This also assumes the request is made using HTTP 1.1 and the POST method.